# usage: Looking forward to

Tags: formal-language

I got a mail from the principal of a school, whom I sent my job application. He replied that he had passed my CV to the HR Committee and they would contact me.

I am confused what I should write him in a reply mail. As I cannot write "I am looking forward to hearing from you" since he had already handed over my Cv to the HR committee, can I write " I am looking forward to hearing from the HR committee of your school" or "I am looking forward to a reply from the HR committee of your school ?"

Comment: What is it about your suggested replies that seems doubtful to you? I don't see an actual questions.

Comment: I am familiar with the expression, "looking forward to hearing from you (a person)", but my doubt is if I am wrong if I write "looking forward to hearing from the HR committee" since HR Committee is not a person.

Comment: Yes you can say that you are looking forward to hearing from a committee.

Answer (score 1):

There's a passage in Oxford Writing Tutor that might help you.

On the other hand, I wouldn't use the last two alternatives you mentioned for they seem to be quite fishy, for you are adressing the principal but you await the official reply from somebody else. The following ending will do if you are really at sea:

**Thank you for your cooperation on this matter.**

[image: from OWT]